# matlab delimiters doesn't work

Tags: matlab, import, delimiter

I have a file test.txt looks like:

datetime    season  holiday workingday  weather atemp   humidity

2011/1/1 0:00   1   0   0   1   cold    high
2011/1/1 1:00  1   0   0   1   cold    high

I want to import them into matlab by delimiter "\t". However, **a=importdata('test.txt','\t')** just import data as a whole rather than separating by \t.

I also try other command like dlmread:

**Error using dlmread (line 139)
  Mismatch between file and format string.
  Trouble reading number from file (row 1u, field 1u) ==>
  datetime  season  holiday workingday  weather atemp
  humidity\n**

then i try  str1=textsacn('test.txt','%s%s%s%s%s%s%s');

**Undefined function 'textsacn' for input arguments of type 'char'.**

My matlab version is 2012a. I use windows.
could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`importdata` and `dlmread` are for numerical data. For a mix text/numerical you have to use `textscan` (you have a typo on `textsacn`) with `fopen` and `fclose`, and then reformat your cell array with `reshape`:

```
fid = fopen('test.txt');
s = textscan(fid,  '%s', 'Delimiter', '\t');
fclose(fid);

s = reshape(s{1}, [7 numel(s{1})/7])';
```

and the output:

```
s = 
    '2011/1/1 0:00'    '1'    '0'    '0'    '1'    'cold'    'high'
    '2011/1/1 1:00'    '1'    '0'    '0'    '1'    'cold'    'high'
```

Then, some strings like `'0'` or `'1'` can be converted to numbers with `str2num`.

Best,

Comment: actually, you code work quite well, thanks in advance. The first feature "datetime" include '2011/1/1 0:00 ', "2011/1/1" and "0:00" are separated by space not tab, but this code also separates them, what should i do to keep them together?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use textscan and specify the numeric format directly:

```
fid = fopen('test.txt');
out = textscan(fid, '%s%d%d%d%d%s%s', 'Delimiter', '\t')
fclose(fid);
```

This way the variable out already contains numbers for the four numeric columns.  You can convert the first column to datenum by doing:

```
dates = datenum(out{1});
```